# Getting daily-air temperature of several months of past years for Australia?

Tags: data, remote-sensing, australia, weather

I really need to obtain the daily-air temperature for several months of 2011. In addition, the data I'm looking for must have the maximum spatial resolution of 1Km*1Km. Since, as I know, there isn't any reliable method to estimate air temp. from satellite imagery, I have to get the data from weather stations available on the internet. However, I haven't found any sites to help me what I need.

Does anyone know how can I get the data for Australia?

Comment: The best you'll be able to get is either modeled or interpolated. The station density is not going to be 1 per 1sqkm in the outback.

Comment: Station data for that density even in Europe would not bee possible. You could interpolate station data or data from forecasts, like [NOAA's weather models](http://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/). The company I am working for can do this for you, if you are interested please contact us at http://www.metgis.com.

Comment: Thank for both the helps. Apart from the spatial resolution, which I decided to accept course data sets, the problem is to find the hourly, say 3 or more, data. I tried to find radiosonde data, but I failed! I even searched for the desired data on the NOAA website but didn't get any luck.

Comment: For open data the best place to ask is often the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.